# Majority vote with different probabilities for classifiers

Tags: probability

I was going through a textbook example (see photo) and I'm unsure how the author got their result. If the probabilities were the same it is just a bernoulli trial problem but they are different and so I am unsure how they arrived at their result. What did the author do?

> **Improving the accuracy by weighting.** Consider an ensemble of $5$ classifiers $D_1, \dots, D_5$ with accuracies $(0.9, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6)$. If the classifiers are independent, the majority vote accuracy (at least $3$ out of $5$ correct votes) is $$\begin{align}P_{maj} &= 3\times 0.9^2\times 0.4\times 0.6 + 0.6^3 + 6\times 0.9\times 0.1\times 0.6^2\times 0.4 \\ &\approx 0.877.\end{align}$$

Comment: Please consider typing your question out with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It makes no sense to have such a huge image with only $4$ lines of text.

Comment: I´ve reduced the size of the photo. It looks more comfortable. This can be done with a snapshot program.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same answer by a slightly different method:

- All of the last three say yes and the first two  do not matter: $(0.6^3) \times (1) = 0.216$
- Two of the last three say yes as do one or two of the first two: $(3 \times 0.6^2 \times 0.4) \times(1-0.1^2) = 0.42768$
- One of the last three say yes as do both of the first two: $(3 \times 0.6 \times 0.4^2) \times(0.9^2) = 0.23328$

and these add up to $0.87696$

They did something similar:

- $3 \times 0.9^2 \times 0.6 \times 0.4$ is both of the first two and one or two of the last three
- $0.6^3$ is all of the last three
- $6 \times 0.9\times 0.1 \times 0.6^2\times 0.4$ is one of the first two and two of the last three

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate on why in the very first expression we multiply by 1? And in the 2nd expression where the (1 - 0.1)^2 comes from?

Comment: @Galois $1$ is the first two not mattering (zero, one or two is certain) while $1-0.1^2$ is one or both (i.e. not zero) of the first two and 0.9^2 is both of the first two